# MapServer Pixmap Symbol GAP for Park Polygon Layer

Tags: cartography, mapserver

I have a

- Polygon layer (National Park)
- PNG Pixmap symbol (from Maki icon set)
- MapServer 5.6

If I use the PNG Pixmap symbol for my Polygon Layer, Mapserver fills the polygon layer with the png symbols.

I tried using

GAP 300

However it doesn't seem to work with pixmap (works fine with vector symbol)

Is there another way to use GAP for pixmap ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if GAP works for pixmap polygon fills with Mapserver version 5 (it does not seem to work in 5.6.7).  I know that it works with Mapserver version 6.
GAP specifies the centre to centre distance, so you need to add the width/height of the pixmap (or the STYLE SIZE, if that is specified) to get the right spacing between the symbols.
See http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html